# Format data in R

Tags: r

I have a excel file that contains data in the following format:

```
Serial          Name          College     Time

Wednesday       24/10/2014
1               StudentA      UA          12:00:00
2               StudentB      UA          13:00:00

Thursday        25/10/2014
3               StudentC      UA          11:00:00
4               StudentA      UA          15:00:00
```

When converted to CSV, it looks like this:

```
Wednesday,24/10/2014,,    
1,StudentA,UA,12:00:00
2,StudentB,UA,13:00:00
```

So, basically, the data is sectioned into a per-day basis. The data for Wednesday, 24/10/2014 is preceded by a row containing Wednesday 24/10/2014 and the same for each day. I want to convert this format to the following:

```
Serial          Name          College        Date          Time
1               StudentA      UA             24/10/2014    12:00:00
2               StudentB      UA             24/10/2014    13:00:00
3               StudentC      UA             25/10/2014    11:00:00
4               StudentA      UA             25/10/2014    15:00:00
```

Feel free to ask any questions and use any tools/technologies. I would prefer R, though, since I'm familiar with it.

Comment: I assume you're writing the data from excel to a tab-delimited or a csv file? Or are you trying to import directly for xls of xlsx file? If the former, can you show the raw data format (specifically being clear about how many delimiters each line has)?

Comment: I'm writing the xlsx file as a csv. I've edited the question to show the format that the csv file has after exporting it as one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very messy format, but here's one way to possibly deal with it. First, just read in the raw lines, then partition the lines depending on special values

```
rr <- readLines("input.csv")
rr <- rr[nchar(rr)>0]  #remove empty lines
ghead <- grepl(",,", rr)  # find the "headers" by looking for two empty columns
glines <- rle(cumsum(ghead [-1]))$lengths-1  #see how many rows each group has

#read header and details lines separately
dd <- read.csv(text=rr[!ghead ])
gg <- read.csv(text=rr[ghead ], header=F, 
    col.names=c("Weekday","Date","X","Y"), 
    colClasses=c("character","character","NULL","NULL")) 

#merge together
cbind(dd, gg[rep(1:nrow(gg), glines),])
```

And this produces

```
    Serial     Name College     Time   Weekday       Date
1        1 StudentA      UA 12:00:00 Wednesday 24/10/2014
1.1      2 StudentB      UA 13:00:00 Wednesday 24/10/2014
2        3 StudentC      UA 11:00:00  Thursday 25/10/2014
2.1      4 StudentA      UA 15:00:00  Thursday 25/10/2014
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that uses [`read.mtable`](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun/blob/master/R/read.mtable.R) from my [GitHub-only "SOfun" package](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun).

```
## Load SOfun (or just copy and paste the required function)
library(SOfun)      ## For `read.mtable`
library(data.table) ## for setnames and rbindlist

## Reads in each chunk as a data.frame in a list
X <- read.mtable("test.csv", chunkId = ",,$", sep = ",")

## Create a vector of new column names
colNames <- c("Serial", "Name", "College", "Time", "Date")

rbindlist(
  lapply(
    ## The next line adds the dates back in
    Map(cbind, X, lapply(strsplit(names(X), ","), `[`, 2)), 
    setnames, colNames))
#    Serial      Name College        Time        Date
# 1:      1  StudentA      UA 12:00:00 PM  24/10/2014
# 2:      2  StudentB      UA 01:00:00 PM  24/10/2014
# 3:      3  StudentC      UA 11:00:00 AM  25/10/2014
# 4:      4  StudentA      UA 03:00:00 PM  25/10/2014
```